# Unity config for generic types

Tags: c#, generics, resharper, unity-container, app-config

I have registered a generic type in a Unity config file. It works, but ReSharper flags this syntax in red as an INCORRECT_TYPE_PARAMETER_NUMBER error. Is there a way to do this that will keep ReSharper happy, without adding overhead to the config file?

```
<unity>
  <type alias="IList`1" type="System.Collections.Generic.IList`1, mscorlib"/>
                                                         ^^^^^^^
  <type alias="List`1" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1, mscorlib"/>
                                                        ^^^^^^
  <type alias="string" type="System.String, mscorlib"/>
  <type alias="int" type="System.Int32, mscorlib"/>
  <register type="IList`1[string]" mapTo="List`1[string], mscorlib"/>
  <register type="IList`1[int]" mapTo="List`1[int], mscorlib"/>
</unity>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried using the full assembly name for mscorlib (including the assembly version, public key token, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, and it makes no difference. I can still control-click through to the underlying type, and R# still shows the warning about generic type params.